# Sort ActiveRecord Query by associated attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

In my Rails app, a project has many steps and images, and steps have many images.

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :steps
  has_many :images
end

class Step < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :images
  belongs_to :project
end

class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :step
end
```

I'd like to do a query where I can retrieve the final image in a project–this would involve determining the last step that has images and fetching the last image in that step.

Currently, I fetch the last image by doing something like @project.default_image:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
 def last_step_with_images
    last_step = ""
    steps.order("published_on DESC").each do |step|
      if step.images.count>0 
        last_step = step
        return last_step
      end
    end
    return last_step
  end

  def default_image
    step_of_last_image = last_step_with_images
    unless step_of_last_image.blank?
        step_of_last_image.last_image
    end
  end
end
```

and in my Step model:

```
  class Step < ActiveRecord::Base
     def last_image
        images.order("position ASC").last if images
     end
  end
```

But I think I can do this much more efficiently with Eager Loading.  I tried to use the following line:

```
@project.images.includes(:step).order("step.published_on")
```

but it returns errors:

```
1.9.3p448 :012 > project.images.includes(:step).order("step.published_on DESC")
  SQL (0.6ms)  SELECT "images"."id" AS t0_r0, "images"."step_id" AS t0_r1, "images"."image_path" AS t0_r2, "images"."created_at" AS t0_r3, "images"."updated_at" AS t0_r4, "images"."caption" AS t0_r5, "images"."project_id" AS t0_r6, "images"."position" AS t0_r7, "images"."saved" AS t0_r8, "images"."video_id" AS t0_r9, "images"."original_id" AS t0_r10, "images"."sound_id" AS t0_r11, "images"."user_id" AS t0_r12, "images"."s3_filepath" AS t0_r13, "steps"."id" AS t1_r0, "steps"."project_id" AS t1_r1, "steps"."name" AS t1_r2, "steps"."position" AS t1_r3, "steps"."description" AS t1_r4, "steps"."created_at" AS t1_r5, "steps"."updated_at" AS t1_r6, "steps"."ancestry" AS t1_r7, "steps"."published_on" AS t1_r8, "steps"."last" AS t1_r9, "steps"."user_id" AS t1_r10, "steps"."original_authors" AS t1_r11, "steps"."label" AS t1_r12, "steps"."label_color" AS t1_r13, "steps"."position_index" AS t1_r14 FROM "images" LEFT OUTER JOIN "steps" ON "steps"."id" = "images"."step_id" WHERE "images"."project_id" = 17 ORDER BY step.published_on DESC
Hirb Error: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "step"
LINE 1: ...tep_id" WHERE "images"."project_id" = 17 ORDER BY step.publi...
                                                             ^
: SELECT "images"."id" AS t0_r0, "images"."step_id" AS t0_r1, "images"."image_path" AS t0_r2, "images"."created_at" AS t0_r3, "images"."updated_at" AS t0_r4, "images"."caption" AS t0_r5, "images"."project_id" AS t0_r6, "images"."position" AS t0_r7, "images"."saved" AS t0_r8, "images"."video_id" AS t0_r9, "images"."original_id" AS t0_r10, "images"."sound_id" AS t0_r11, "images"."user_id" AS t0_r12, "images"."s3_filepath" AS t0_r13, "steps"."id" AS t1_r0, "steps"."project_id" AS t1_r1, "steps"."name" AS t1_r2, "steps"."position" AS t1_r3, "steps"."description" AS t1_r4, "steps"."created_at" AS t1_r5, "steps"."updated_at" AS t1_r6, "steps"."ancestry" AS t1_r7, "steps"."published_on" AS t1_r8, "steps"."last" AS t1_r9, "steps"."user_id" AS t1_r10, "steps"."original_authors" AS t1_r11, "steps"."label" AS t1_r12, "steps"."label_color" AS t1_r13, "steps"."position_index" AS t1_r14 FROM "images" LEFT OUTER JOIN "steps" ON "steps"."id" = "images"."step_id" WHERE "images"."project_id" = 17 ORDER BY step.published_on DESC
    .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-3.2.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1163:in `exec'
    .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-3.2.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1163:in `exec_no_cache'
    .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-3.2.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:660:in `block in exec_query'
    .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-3.2.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:280:in `block in log'
    .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activesupport-3.2.15/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
    .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-3.2.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:275:in `log'
    .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-3.2.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:659:in `exec_query'
    .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-3.2.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1262:in `select'
    .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-3.2.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:18:in `select_all'
    .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-3.2.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:63:in `select_all'
    .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-3.2.15/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:212:in `find_with_associations'
    .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-3.2.15/lib/active_record/relation.rb:171:in `exec_queries'
    .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-3.2.15/lib/active_record/relation.rb:160:in `block in to_a'
    .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-3.2.15/lib/active_record/explain.rb:34:in `logging_query_plan'
    .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-3.2.15/lib/active_record/relation.rb:159:in `to_a'
    .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-3.2.15/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:6:in `to_ary'
    .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/hirb-0.7.1/lib/hirb/formatter.rb:88:in `Array'
    .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/hirb-0.7.1/lib/hirb/formatter.rb:88:in `determine_output_class'
    .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/hirb-0.7.1/lib/hirb/formatter.rb:53:in `format_output'
    .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/hirb-0.7.1/lib/hirb/view.rb:204:in `render_output'
    .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/hirb-0.7.1/lib/hirb/view.rb:123:in `view_output'
    .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/hirb-0.7.1/lib/hirb/view.rb:200:in `view_or_page_output'
    .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/hirb-0.7.1/lib/hirb/view.rb:186:in `output_value'
    .rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb.rb:160:in `block (2 levels) in eval_input'
    .rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb.rb:273:in `signal_status'
    .rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb.rb:156:in `block in eval_input'
    .rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/ruby-lex.rb:243:in `block (2 levels) in each_top_level_statement'
    .rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/ruby-lex.rb:229:in `loop'
    .rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/ruby-lex.rb:229:in `block in each_top_level_statement'
    .rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/ruby-lex.rb:228:in `catch'
    .rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/ruby-lex.rb:228:in `each_top_level_statement'
    .rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb.rb:155:in `eval_input'
    .rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb.rb:70:in `block in start'
    .rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb.rb:69:in `catch'
    .rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb.rb:69:in `start'
    .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/railties-3.2.15/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
    .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/railties-3.2.15/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/railties-3.2.15/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
    script/rails:6:in `require'
    script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

**Edit**

Here is my error log when I try to execute the following in my console:

```
@project.images.joins(:step).order('step.published_on')

 Image Load (59.7ms)  SELECT "images".* FROM "images" INNER JOIN "steps" ON "steps"."id" = "images"."step_id" WHERE "images"."project_id" = 17 ORDER BY step.published_on
Hirb Error: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "step"
LINE 1: ...tep_id" WHERE "images"."project_id" = 17 ORDER BY step.publi...
                                                             ^
: SELECT "images".* FROM "images" INNER JOIN "steps" ON "steps"."id" = "images"."step_id" WHERE "images"."project_id" = 17 ORDER BY step.published_on
    .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-3.2.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1163:in `exec'
    .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-3.2.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1163:in `exec_no_cache'
    .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-3.2.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:660:in `block in exec_query'
    .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-3.2.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:280:in `block in log'
    .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activesupport-3.2.15/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
    .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-3.2.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:275:in `log'
    .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-3.2.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:659:in `exec_query'
    .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-3.2.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1262:in `select'
    .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-3.2.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:18:in `select_all'
    .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-3.2.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:63:in `select_all'
    .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-3.2.15/lib/active_record/querying.rb:38:in `block in find_by_sql'
    .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-3.2.15/lib/active_record/explain.rb:41:in `logging_query_plan'
    .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-3.2.15/lib/active_record/querying.rb:37:in `find_by_sql'
    .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-3.2.15/lib/active_record/relation.rb:171:in `exec_queries'
    .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-3.2.15/lib/active_record/relation.rb:160:in `block in to_a'
    .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-3.2.15/lib/active_record/explain.rb:34:in `logging_query_plan'
    .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-3.2.15/lib/active_record/relation.rb:159:in `to_a'
    .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-3.2.15/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:6:in `to_ary'
    .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/hirb-0.7.1/lib/hirb/formatter.rb:88:in `Array'
    .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/hirb-0.7.1/lib/hirb/formatter.rb:88:in `determine_output_class'
    .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/hirb-0.7.1/lib/hirb/formatter.rb:53:in `format_output'
    .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/hirb-0.7.1/lib/hirb/view.rb:204:in `render_output'
    .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/hirb-0.7.1/lib/hirb/view.rb:123:in `view_output'
    .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/hirb-0.7.1/lib/hirb/view.rb:200:in `view_or_page_output'
    .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/hirb-0.7.1/lib/hirb/view.rb:186:in `output_value'
    .rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb.rb:160:in `block (2 levels) in eval_input'
    .rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb.rb:273:in `signal_status'
    .rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb.rb:156:in `block in eval_input'
    .rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/ruby-lex.rb:243:in `block (2 levels) in each_top_level_statement'
    .rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/ruby-lex.rb:229:in `loop'
    .rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/ruby-lex.rb:229:in `block in each_top_level_statement'
    .rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/ruby-lex.rb:228:in `catch'
    .rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/ruby-lex.rb:228:in `each_top_level_statement'
    .rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb.rb:155:in `eval_input'
    .rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb.rb:70:in `block in start'
    .rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb.rb:69:in `catch'
    .rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb.rb:69:in `start'
    .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/railties-3.2.15/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
    .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/railties-3.2.15/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/railties-3.2.15/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
    script/rails:6:in `require'
    script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Does anyone know how to use eager loading for such a query?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that `includes` just reduce the 1+N issue, if you check the SQL generated by `@project.images.includes(:step)`, it should be something like this:

`SELECT * from images WHERE images.project_id = 2`

`SELECT * from steps WHERE steps.image_id IN (1,2,3,4,5)`

As you see in the query, it fetchs images then steps belong to each image. You may need to do JOIN instead.

`@project.images.joins(:step).order('steps.published_on')`

This will return the images ordered by published_on of step, and if you also want to use the attributes from step, try something like this:

`@project.images.joins(:step).order('steps.published_on').select('images.*, steps.field_1 AS step_field1, steps.field_2 AS step_field2')`

Let me know if it helps!

Comment: thanks for your help!  I tried out your suggestion, but I get the following error: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "step"  Any idea how to resolve it?

Comment: Are you able to do JOIN `@project.images.joins(:step)`?

Comment: yes, I'm able to do @project.images.joins(:step).  It's when I add the ordering that I get an error.

Comment: Could you please show the result for `@project.images.joins(:step).to_sql`?

Comment: "SELECT \"images\".* FROM \"images\" INNER JOIN \"steps\" ON \"steps\".\"id\" = \"images\".\"step_id\" WHERE \"images\".\"project_id\" = 17"

Comment: thanks for your help.  I edited my original post to show the error.

Comment: Well, I got the problem. It was my mistake actually, please change from `step.published_on` to `steps.published_on`, `steps` need to be plural corresponds to the table name. Sorry that I wasted your time alot, I edited the answer.